# How to get the users account info from Wordpress into JApplet

Tags: java, security, wordpress, cookies, applet

I (will) have a `JApplet` embedded in a Wordpress.org installation (either on a page or in a post) via [a plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/java-applet-embed/).

I would like to get the Wordpress email address (or other account info like ID) of the user that uses the `JApplet`, and store it - together with a result s/he's scored in a game (the `JApplet`) - in a database.

Is there a way to access this information from within the applet, perhaps by way of cookies or similar?

Btw, yes, all users are informed that this information will be stored, etc. Only users that are already logged in can access the applet anyway.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend passing that information into the applet via parameters substituted by PHP that provides the proper Wordpress values through the Wordpress API.

Comment: Ah thanks! I've found a number of examples on the web for how to achieve this after your first prompt. Easy peasy :).